# In the Kok cycle occurring in Photosystem II's Oxygen-evolving Complex, what exactly does P680 do?

Tags: photosynthesis, chloroplasts

I've been reading up on the oxygen-evolving complex using a few sources, but am a non-biology major so my understanding might be somewhat/very flawed. I've been using this source mainly:

[https://faculty.missouri.edu/~glaserr/3700s13/PS-Review2.pdf](https://faculty.missouri.edu/%7Eglaserr/3700s13/PS-Review2.pdf)

and have so far gathered that, along phases S0 to S4, the Mn complex holds onto the 2 water molecules while it is "oxidized" by P680 with the help of tyrosine Yz; instead of oxidizing water directly, P680 oxidizes a total of 4 Oxidizing Equivalents, which act as "stand-ins" for the redox reaction involving water. At the final stage, the Mn complex has a total charge of 4+, which then causes the 2 oxygen atoms (from 2 H20) to give up their  electrons and turn into molecular oxygen, something this source also says:

https://www.life.illinois.edu/crofts/bioph354/lect25.html

My preliminary question is, is my understanding correct at a basic level? And if it is, then what is P680 doing?

We've been told that it's one of the strongest organic oxidizing agents, which made me think that it stripped the hydrogen from H20 immediately, but instead it seems like the "splitting" of water occurs in the Mn complex thanks to the 4 oxidizing equivalents.

Is P680's role still essential in this process? As in, is P680's strength the only natural thing that can oxidize the Mn complex at each step so that it eventually splits the water? Or am I misunderstanding the "water-splitting" step entirely?